# Xamarin/MonoTouch UITableView cache

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, uilabel, xamarin

I have a UITableView which I'm filling with images and labels.  In my source class I create  a UILabel for each cell:

```cs
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);

        //if there are no cells create a new one
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
        cell.UserInteractionEnabled = false;

        //create a new cellobject - this grabs the image and returns a CGBitmapContext
        CellObject _cellObject = new CellObject();
        cell.ImageView.Image = _cellObject.DrawCell(treasures[indexPath.Row].cellImage);

        //add text
        UILabel secondViewLabel = new UILabel();
        secondViewLabel.Text = treasures[indexPath.Row].cellTitle;
        Console.WriteLine("The title is: " + treasures[indexPath.Row].cellTitle); 
        secondViewLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        secondViewLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        secondViewLabel.Lines = 0;
        secondViewLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        secondViewLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 16);
        secondViewLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(205, 54, 51);

        //get the width of the text
        SizeF labelSize = secondViewLabel.StringSize(secondViewLabel.Text, secondViewLabel.Font);

        secondViewLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 110 - (labelSize.Height + 10), labelSize.Width + 20, labelSize.Height + 10);

        //add a second view
        UIView secondView = new UIView();
        secondView.AddSubview(secondViewLabel);
        cell.ContentView.AddSubview(secondView);


        return cell;
    }
```

Which builds the table perfectly, however it seems that each cell is getting the UILabel for every other cell as well as it's own.  I can see this on shorter labels, you can see the other labels behind.  I'm loading and parsing the XML to a list, and working off that list:

```cs
List<Treasure> treasures = new List<Treasure>();

    protected class Treasure {
        public string cellTitle { get; set; }
        public string cellTag { get; set; }
        public string cellImage { get; set; }
        public string audioFile { get; set; }
        public string mainTitle { get; set; }
        public string mainTag { get; set; }
        public string mainBody { get; set; }
        public string mainImage { get; set; }
        public string mainCaption { get; set; }
    }

    public CellSource (/*string[] items*/)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CellSource called");
        string fileName = "treasuresiPhone.xml";
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
        treasures = doc.Descendants("treasures").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("treasure").Select(p=> new Treasure() {
            cellTitle = p.Element("celltitle").Value,
            cellTag = p.Element("celltagline").Value,
            cellImage = p.Element("cellimage").Value
        }).ToList();

        numCells = treasures.Count();

    }
```

Any ideas or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating new `UILabel` each `GetCell` call is a bit weak:

- Time to create new UI object and set it's properties in frequently called method;
- GC could eat your `UILabel` cause not explicit link to it exists.

Try other solution:

- Create your own subclass of `UITableViewCell`;
- Then, declare `UILabel` property in it;
- Then, when dequeue cell try to cast cell to your type. If it's not null, set it's label's text property to new value.

Answer (score 1):

If you dequeue a cell it will already have the subviews (`UILabels`) you added. The cell is serialized as whole, with all the views you added upon creation.
So: if you don't want to subclass `UITableViewCell`, assign Tag values to your custom views and use `ViewWithTag` to access them.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```cs
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);

        cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier);
        cell.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
        UILabel secondViewLabel = new UILabel();

        //if there are no cells create a new one
        if (cell == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("cell == null");
        } else {

            //create a new cellobject - this grabs the image and returns a CGBitmapContext
            CellObject _cellObject = new CellObject();
            cell.ImageView.Image = _cellObject.DrawCell(treasures[indexPath.Row].cellImage);

            //add text
            secondViewLabel.Tag = 1;
            secondViewLabel.Text = treasures[indexPath.Row].cellTitle;
            Console.WriteLine("The title is: " + treasures[indexPath.Row].cellTitle); 
            secondViewLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            secondViewLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            secondViewLabel.Lines = 0;
            secondViewLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            secondViewLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 16);
            secondViewLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(205, 54, 51);

            //get the width of the text
            SizeF labelSize = secondViewLabel.StringSize(secondViewLabel.Text, secondViewLabel.Font);

            secondViewLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 110 - (labelSize.Height + 10), labelSize.Width + 20, labelSize.Height + 10);

            //add a second view
            UIView secondView = new UIView();
            secondView.AddSubview(secondViewLabel);
            cell.ContentView.AddSubview(secondView);
        }
        return cell;
    }
```